# Launching other apps from your MainActivity and back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio-3.0

Would like to launch applications like Google Map, IMO, Gallery from my MainActivity. After Launch if the user hits the back button they should wind up in the MainActivity.

I have created an Intent with package names and started the Activity. The problem is the back button takes the user to phone's screen and completely out of the Main App.

```
public void openMap (View view) {
    Log.i("openMap", "Entered openMap");
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        try {
           // startActivity(launchIntent);
            startActivityForResult(launchIntent,100, Bundle.EMPTY );
            finish();
        } // in case Instagram not installed in your device
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("openImo", "Intent is null");
    }

 }//startActivityForResult allows onActivityResult
}
```

The back button just does not get back to the Main Activity. It goes to the Operating System and the Phone Screen.

Comment: you have write  finish(); thats why your activity is finished.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are finishing the activity. Try the below snippet.

```
public void openMap (View view) {
    Log.i("openMap", "Entered openMap");
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        try {
           // startActivity(launchIntent);
            startActivityForResult(launchIntent,100, Bundle.EMPTY );
        } // in case Instagram not installed in your device
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("openImo", "Intent is null");
    }

 }//startActivityForResult allows onActivityResult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed them all.
Most of my other Activities work correctly now.
There is an IMO app which does not want to go back to Main Activity.
After hitting the back button, it asks: Complete Action Using:
Home, Home & app drawer, EasyHome
Any one of them takes me back to the Phone's Screen.

```
public void openImo (View view) {
    Log.i("openImo", "Entered openImo");
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.imo.android.imous");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        try {
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        } // in case Instagram not installed in your device
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("openImo", "Intent is null");
    }
}
```

I still have issues with this. All apps go back to Main Activity but IMO! Upon pressing the back button it goes to the Phone's main screen!